# Use SDP to get devices haveing certain UUID on Android 2.3.x

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid, sdp

Given the UUID used in SDP of the Bluetooth run a discovery query to know the Bluetooth devices who are using the same UUID without connecting with them. I want a solution for Android 2.3.x.

Answer (score 1):

The `fetchUuidsWithSdp()` API allows you to see which UUIDs are supported on remote devices.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#fetchUuidsWithSdp

Comment: I asked the question for Android 2.3.x. These functions are for Android 4.0.x.

Comment: Just change the API level in the dropdown on the left hand side. I don't think the Bluetooth APIs have changed much between 2.3.x and 4.2.2 anyway.

Comment: Yea use the newest API but keep the target 2.3.x - Some minor things like the theme widgets will not work... but you obviously do not need those.

Comment: They are available also in Android 2.3.3 ..just hidden. Use reflection to call them